# Using gsub in awk

Tags: awk

Please find below the input files – file1 and file2, and get the output as in file3.

Please use – GSUB in awk

File1:

```
000000018*A00045425530
000000022*A00002122779
000000032*A00051046521
000000035*A00008977353
000000052*A00050659539
```

File 2:

```
A00045425530 *204***204***0.01**********1**1*****18**0****1***********0.01***0**0***0                    (EOR)
A00020515159 *6071***6071*************1**1*****26**0****1***0*0**0***0*****0**0***0                    (EOR)
A00002122779 *****************1*************1****************0***0                    (EOR)
A00002293889 ********************************************0**0***0                    (EOR)
A00008977353 *****************1*************1****************0***0                    (EOR)
```

Match AGN (field 2 from file1 and field 1 from File 2) and also remove “                    (EOR)” from the matched output to null using gsub in awk. The output should be as follows:

File3 Output:

```
A00045425530 *204***204***0.01**********1**1*****18**0****1***********0.01***0**0***0
A00002122779 *****************1*************1****************0***0
A00008977353 *****************1*************1****************0***0
```

Comment: wrt `Please use – GSUB in awk` - why do you care how we do it? Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2] }
  NR!=FNR && $1 in a{
    gsub(/\s+\(EOR\)/, "")
    print
  }
' FS='*' file1 FS=' ' file2 > file3
```

When the first file is read, use `*` as input field separator and use the second field as index for array `a` (with empty value).
When the second file is read, use the space character as input field separator and test if the first field exists as index in array `a`.
If the condition is true, replace any space characters followed by `(EOR)` with an empty string and print the current line. The output is redirected to `file3`.